# Getting the Nth digit after the decimal point in Java

Tags: java, decimal

How can I get the Nth digit after the decimal point, using Java?

**For example:**

If the decimal number is `64890.1527`, then:

- 1st digit is 1
- 2nd digit is 5
- 3rd digit is 2

and so on ..

Comment: What have you tried so far? Try to post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @ericbn Unfortunately, I wasn't be able to make any code but here is what I am trying to do : if I have a float that have 2 numbers after the decimal point , I want to check if the SECOND number is bigger than 5 or not ?! I have no idea how can I do it.

Comment: Be aware that 5.26 cannot be exactly represented as a floating point value. [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: float x = (float) 5.26; this is how I used to write it . Is this wrong sir?

Comment: float x = 5.26f; is the way to write it.

Comment: Thank you sir! but can you tell me what's the difference between using float num = 0.12438f; and  float num = (float) 0.12438; ??

Comment: If you do float x = (float) 5.26 you are casting to a float from a double which in effect is doing an implicit conversion from double to float and can result in a loss of precision. Such and assignment can in fact result in two different numbers being represented (one on the left and one on the right). A float is a 32 bit number and double is 64 bits. Try comparing a float rep of a number to the double equivalent using == and you will see that they don't always equate. For example if (1.32f == 1.32) vs if (6f == 6). You shouldn't mix the two in the manner above.

Comment: @SalmaHassan thank you for keeping this question up despite the downvotes!  great question!  not sure why it got so derailed with this talk of exact representation . . .

Comment: Dear @dbliss, I haven't logged in to this account for ages and I just saw your comment, thank you! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Getting the Nth Decimal of a Float**

Here is a trick for getting the Nth decimal place of a float:

- Take the absolute value
- Multiply by 10<sup>n</sup>
- Cast to an int
- Modulus by 10

**Example**

Get the third decimal of 0.12438. We would expect the answer to be 4.

- 0.12438

  - Take the absolute value
- 0.12438

  - Multiply by 10<sup>3</sup>
- 124.38

  - Cast to an int
- 124

  - Modulus by 10
- 4

**How It Works**

Multiplying by 10<sup>n</sup> gets the decimal you care about into the ones place. Casting to an int drops the decimals. Modulus by 10 drops all but the ones place.

We take the absolute value in case the input is negative.

**Code Snippet**

```
float num = 0.12438f;
int thirdDecimal = (int)(Math.abs(num) * Math.pow(10,3)) % 10; // Equals 4
int fifthDecimal = (int)(Math.abs(num) * Math.pow(10,4)) % 10; // Equals 3
```

Comment: Do you mean 10 to the power of n, or 10 XOR n?  Because you have the latter there.

Comment: @Makoto Whoops. Thanks for catching that. I haven't been actually coding in Java for a while.

Comment: It seems like you're in C# (somewhat, although I'm sure it uses caret for XOR) - you've got `Pow` capitalized when it shouldn't be.  I know what your'e going for, so I edited your multiplication statement, but decided to leave the code alone.

Comment: @Makoto I misunderstood the question when I read it for the first time. The OP didn't want the first N decimals. The OP wanted the Nth decimal. I think I fixed it.

Comment: YES , this is exactly what I am trying to do ! Thank you very much sir.
But I don't know why when I ran the code and print "fifthDecimal" it printed out 7 instead of 8 , while "thridDecimal" was correct !!

Comment: This won't compile unless you change to use float num = 0.12438f;

Comment: Yes I did that before running the program , should I edit the answer too ?

Comment: @SalmaHassan I fixed it. Only the author is allowed to make 1 character edits to an answer, unfortunately.

Comment: @Rainbolt fair enough.  i'm using python, not java, so that may be the difference.  the difference between floats and doubles isn't something i pay attention to, so i'm interested in a general solution for all of these.  but you're right -- the question was about floats.  either way, taking the absolute value at the very end does nothing, i'm pretty sure.  (bolded comment above removed.)

Comment: @dbliss When you put it like that, it makes sense to change the answer. One moment. Edit: There, it is fixed. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the best solution, but...

Make a string of it;
Loop through the string;
Check what you wanna check.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a `Double` and call `toString` on it and then iterate over charArray like this

```
public class TestIndexOf {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Double d = 5.26;
        String source = d.toString();

        char[] chars = source.toCharArray();

        char max = source.charAt(source.length() - 1);
        boolean isMax = true;
        for (char aChar : chars) {
            if (max < aChar) {
                max = aChar;
                isMax = false;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(max + " is max?" + isMax);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not converting `double` to `String`.  That's taking a `Double` and converting it to a `String`.  Subtle difference.