# Finding decimal value based on input number

Tags: c#, decimal

If i has decimal `number = 0.26579`
My input is `int = 3`
the value I want to get from decimal number is 5
Is there a solution i can find this value?

```
private decimal decimalNumber = 0.26579
private int decimalPosition =3;
private int decimalPositionValue = 0;

public void getdecimalPositionValue(){
// the result I want is 5 which is decimalPosition = 3 and get it in decimalPositionValue 
}
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26048153/getting-the-nth-decimal-of-a-float) help?

Comment: Add the code you have tried to do please

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting the Nth Decimal of a Float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26048153/getting-the-nth-decimal-of-a-float)

Comment: The *Getting the Nth Decimal of a Float in JAVA* does not work in C# as is.

Comment: Times it by 10 to the power of 3 (i.e. 1000). Then use `% 10` to get the last digit (i.e. 5).

Answer (score -1):

convert the decimal to string, split by the dot and them take a substring, of length 1 at the desired position.

also make sure that the decimal has, decimal part

```
  using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        decimal decimalNumber = 0.26579M;
        int decimalPosition =3;
        int decimalPositionValue = 0;
        Console.WriteLine(getdecimalPositionValue(decimalNumber, decimalPosition));
    }



    public static int getdecimalPositionValue(decimal num, int pos)
    {
    return int.Parse(num.ToString().Split('.')[1].Substring(pos -1, 1));
    }
}
```